# how to install libc6 2.34 from sources?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, glibc

I'm running Linux Mint 20.2 Uma and I'm trying to upgrade the linux kernel version. I want to install the kernel version 5.15rc3 but the problem is that after I download the .deb packages from the mainline ([https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D)) and I `dpkg -i *.deb` them I have this error.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic depends on linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3 is not installed.
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.
```

As I understand I need to have the libc6 installed. Currently there is no libc6 version 2.34 already compiled for linux mint so I have to do it myself.
I've done the steps from "Building glibc without installing" https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds and I've got the lib built but what do I need to do now in order to install it? I should just copy and paste the output of the build over my root folder?

Comment: Your link tells how to install . But : **The OS may not survive** → glibc *is* your OS (together with the kernel). ..... The easy way to use glibc-2.34 : Install Ubuntu 21.10 or Fedora 35, both have glibc-2.34 .

Answer (score 0):

It is better to build the kernel by yourself. According to my tests, when using make-kpkg to build the deb package of the kernel, only the kernel package matching the current system environment (libc6) version will be generated. while using the make deb-pkg parameter to build the kernel package will generate the package, In addition to the standard kernel package, a new deb package matching libc6 that compiles the kernel version source code  will be generated. For example, I used make deb-pkg to compile from the 6.6.1 kernel source code under Debian 11 and got an additional 2.38 version of the deb package.